# Bubblewrap Cli Error unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

I couldn't run the command

```
bubblewrap init --manifest="https://mydomain/manifest.json"
```

I got error

> cli ERROR unable to get local issuer certificate

I tried to set false "**strict-ssl**" also tried to configure

```
npm config set cafile "file/-path.crt"
```

but unable to fix this error.

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem? I've got the same issue now.